Is there a formal algebraic theory for recursive/inductive operators (lookup question: couldn't find after searching)
I'm aware of recursive functions in computer programming.
Surprisingly I was having trouble finding similar books and articles on recursive or inductive mathematical structures (that is, in situations more general than that of computer science). Here is a simple example of the sort of thing I am looking for: On the natural numbers, define a function $ f : \mathbb N \rightarrow \mathbb N $ as such:
First with the base case
$$ f (0) = 0 $$
and (inductively)
$$ f(n) = f(n-1)  +1$$
I'm sure this is a well studied field outside of computer science, as there are plenty of mathematical structures that can be defined this way, but I must be missing a keyword or something, as I can't find any pages or books on the theory that could, for instance, involve things like automorphisms, more general endomorphisms, or transforms. Keep in mind that I'm not an algebraist, so be gentle. The book and article recommendations are highly welcome.

I can't really tell what you're asking. Your function is an example of a definition by cases as is commonly done in set theory, but could easily be reinterpreted as a definition by pattern matching (thus using the recursion principle of $\mathbb{N}$ seen as an inductive type, although your function isn't recursive). What does this have to do with generators?

I was anticipating that given my natural numbers argument, someone might bring up using $1$ as a generators. No: I don't care about generators, and removed them from the question. I just want to know the field of math that studies these recursive/inductive algebraic structures. I tried to look through Fraleigh's book and couldn't find anything. Ditto for an internet search.

Which part is it that you want? The infinite composition? Or just general recursive definition?

@Trebor General recursive definition, I was using $\infty$ as a notational shorthand. I'm interested in recursive algebras that can be repeated over and over. Operations similar to curried addition and multiplication, but perhaps with an operation that begins with a "base case" and then defines its structure inductively from that "base case"

I think I gave too nice and simple of a definition. The new function $f$ that I defined is a more serious looking form of induction, while still being fairly simple.

Recursion is pretty much the same thing as mathematical induction. Your $f$ can be rewritten as $f(0)=0$ and $f(S(n))=f(n)+1$, where $S(n)$ is the successor function. That's just induction.

yeah, I was wondering if there if there was an algebraic name for these operations though. For instance, if a set is equipped with a binary operation that's defined and build inductively from a "base case", then is there a name for that kind of binary operation?

Wouldn't it be odd if a binary operation was named after how it's defined (its intension) rather than what it is (its extension)?

@Nate yes, the name is "inductive" or "recursive" binary opration. Btw, you cannot separate yourself from natural numbers. Recursive structures don't exist without natural numbers, or more generally well ordered sets.

@freakish: It's not quite accurate to say that recursive definitions like these ones are just induction. One can prove, by induction, that if $f,g:\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$ are functions such that $f(0)=g(0)=0$ and $f(S(n))=S(f(n))$ and $g(S(n))=S(g(n))$, then $f=g$. However, to prove that there exists a function $f:\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$ with this property, you can't simply appeal to induction. In axiomatic set theory, you would typically use the Recursion Theorem.

(The version of the recursion theorem given on Wikipedia doesn't allow $f(S(n))$ to be defined in terms of $f(n)$, but more general versions of the recursion theorem do.)

@Joe In axiomatic set theory, the argument that shows that such a function $f$ exists uses exactly an inductive argument (on $\omega +1$).

@JonathanSchilhan: I'm not quite sure which argument you are referring to, but at least in Naive Set Theory by Paul Halmos, the proof of the recursion theorem does use induction. However, I wouldn't say that it is just an inductive proof. Halmos proceeds by constructing a set $f$ explicitly as a set of ordered pairs, before proving by induction that $f$ is a function. It is the construction of $f$ that I don't consider to involve induction.

Recursive definitions of functions appear in virtually every area of mathematics, but I'm not aware of any area of mathematics that is devoted solely to their study. However, recursion and induction are studied in most detail in any area of mathematics that considers foundational issues more generally. The traditional foundation of mathematics is axiomatic set theory, and the most widely studied set theory is $\mathsf{ZFC}$. Here is what Paul Halmos has to say about recursion in his book Naive Set Theory (I have made a few modifications to the notation, but otherwise entirely preserved the quote):

Induction is often used not only to prove things but also to define things. Suppose, to be specific, that $f$ is a function from a set $X$ into the same set $X$, and suppose that $a$ is an element of $X$. It seems natural to try to define an infinite sequence $(u_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ of elements of $X$ (that is, a function $u$ from $\mathbb N$ to $X$) in some such way as this: write $u_0=a$, $u_1 = f(u_0)$, $u_2=f(u_1)$, and so on. If the would-be definer were pressed to explain the "and so on," he might lean on induction. What it all means, he might say, is that we define $u_0$ as $a$, and then, inductively, we define $u_{S(n)}$ as $f(u_n)$ for every $n$. This may sound plausible, but, as justification for an existential assertion, it is insufficient. The principle of mathematical induction does indeed prove, easily, that there can be at most one function satisfying all the stated conditions, but it does not establish the existence of such a function. What is needed is the following result.


Recursion theorem. If $a$ is an element of a set $X$, and if $f$ is a function from $X$ into $X$, then there exists a function $u$ from $\mathbb N$ into $X$ such that $u_0=a$ and such that $u_{S(n)} =f(u_n)$ for all $n$ in $\mathbb N$.

The proof of the recursion theorem can be found in Halmos's book, and in many other introductory books on mathematical logic and set theory. Once we have the recursion theorem in hand, we can now turn to your example. You want to prove that there is a sequence $u:\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$ such that $u_0=0$ and $u_{S(n)}=S(u_n)=u_n+1$. (I have rewritten your definition so as to avoid subtraction – subtraction in the context of the natural numbers is often awkward to deal with, as $a-b$ only makes sense when $a\ge b$.) In this particular case, we can recognise that $u:\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$ is simply the identity function on $\mathbb N$, and so it is easy to prove the existence of $u$: we can define the set $g=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb N\times\mathbb N:x=y\}$, and then prove by induction that $u=g$. However, what if $u$ had a more complicated definition? Perhaps we attempted to "define" $u$ by specifying a set $X$, an $a\in X$, and a function $\phi:\mathbb N\times X\to X$, before setting
\begin{align}
u_0&=a \\[3pt]
u_{S(n)}&=\phi(n,u_n) \, .
\end{align}
Here, it is not immediately clear how to apply the recursion theorem, as the definition of $u_{S(n)}$ appears to depend on both $n$ and $u_n$, not just $n$. However, with a bit more work, we can in fact prove a version of the recursion theorem that allows for these more general kinds of definitions. You can find the details in this post, for example.

Other foundations of mathematics exist. In homotopy type theory, the picture is much simpler: inductive types are primitive and they come equipped with an induction principle that specialises to a recursion principle in the non-dependent case. HoTT can interpret (and be interpreted in) ZFC set theory.

@NaïmFavier: Thanks for your comment. I didn't intend to suggest in my post that ZFC is the only foundation for mathematics, or even the best one – just that it is the best known one. But from what I little I know about homotopy type theory, I can see the appeal that it would have for someone with a computer science background.

@NaïmFavier has HoTT been completely worked out as a foundation for mathematics? I haven't been following closely, but the last time I had checked, it was still a work in progress.

@CheerfulParsnip depends on who you ask, and what you mean by "completely worked out", but from my POV yes.
